# SQL Server triggers deadlocking - SQL Updates

Tags: sql-server

I picked up a project to troubleshoot some SQL Triggers that are deadlocking. The example code here is one of the triggers that updates fields. I am wondering if due to the number to Updates, is this Trigger running into locking issues?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[PAACS_CaseLog_UpdateForeignKeys]
    ON  [dbo].[PAACS_CaseLog]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF ((SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(0, 'AFTER', 'DML')) < 2)
    BEGIN

        UPDATE upTarget
        SET upTarget.UK_casetimingid = forTarget.UniqueID
        FROM PAACS_CaseLog upTarget
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_CaseTiming forTarget ON forTarget.id = upTarget.casetiming_id
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_CaseTiming currentTarget ON currentTarget.UniqueId = upTarget.UK_CaseTimingId
        WHERE upTarget.UK_casetimingid IS NULL OR forTarget.id <> currentTarget.id

        UPDATE upTarget
        SET upTarget.UK_Operating_Surgeon_id = forTarget.UniqueID
        FROM PAACS_CaseLog upTarget 
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_ShortTermFaculty forTarget ON forTarget.id = upTarget.Operating_Surgeon_id
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_ShortTermFaculty currentTarget ON currentTarget.UniqueId = upTarget.UK_Operating_Surgeon_Id
        WHERE upTarget.UK_Operating_Surgeon_id IS NULL AND upTarget.Operating_Surgeon_id IS NOT NULL OR forTarget.id <> currentTarget.id

        UPDATE upTarget
        SET upTarget.UK_Surgeon_on_Chart = forTarget.UniqueID
        FROM PAACS_CaseLog upTarget
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_ShortTermFaculty forTarget ON forTarget.id = upTarget.Surgeon_on_Chart
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_ShortTermFaculty currentTarget ON currentTarget.UniqueId = upTarget.UK_Surgeon_on_Chart
        WHERE upTarget.UK_Surgeon_on_Chart IS NULL AND upTarget.Surgeon_on_Chart IS NOT NULL OR forTarget.id <> currentTarget.id

        UPDATE upTarget
        SET upTarget.UK_surgeonrole_id = forTarget.UniqueID
        FROM PAACS_CaseLog upTarget
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_PickListItem forTarget ON forTarget.PickListItemId = upTarget.surgeonrole_id
            LEFT JOIN PAACs_PickListItem currentTarget ON currentTarget.UniqueId = upTarget.UK_surgeonrole_id
        WHERE upTarget.UK_surgeonrole_id IS NULL AND upTarget.surgeonrole_id IS NOT NULL OR forTarget.PickListItemId <> currentTarget.PickListItemId

        UPDATE upTarget
        SET upTarget.UK_assistant_id = forTarget.UniqueID
        FROM PAACS_CaseLog upTarget
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_ShortTermFaculty forTarget ON forTarget.id = upTarget.assistant_id
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_ShortTermFaculty currentTarget ON currentTarget.UniqueId = upTarget.UK_assistant_id
        WHERE upTarget.UK_assistant_id IS NULL AND upTarget.assistant_id IS NOT NULL OR forTarget.id <> currentTarget.id

        UPDATE upTarget
        SET upTarget.UK_assistantrole_id = forTarget.UniqueID
        FROM PAACS_CaseLog upTarget
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_PickListItem forTarget ON forTarget.PickListItemId = upTarget.assistantrole_id
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_PickListItem currentTarget ON currentTarget.UniqueId = upTarget.UK_assistantrole_id
        WHERE upTarget.UK_assistantrole_id IS NULL AND upTarget.assistantrole_id IS NOT NULL OR forTarget.PickListItemId <> currentTarget.PickListItemId

        UPDATE upTarget
        SET upTarget.UK_assistant2_id = forTarget.UniqueID
        FROM PAACS_CaseLog upTarget
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_ShortTermFaculty forTarget ON forTarget.id = upTarget.assistant2_id
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_ShortTermFaculty currentTarget ON currentTarget.UniqueId = upTarget.UK_assistant2_id
        WHERE upTarget.UK_assistant2_id IS NULL AND upTarget.assistant2_id IS NOT NULL OR forTarget.id <> currentTarget.id

        UPDATE upTarget
        SET upTarget.UK_assistant2role_id = forTarget.UniqueID
        FROM PAACS_CaseLog upTarget
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_PickListItem forTarget ON forTarget.PickListItemId = upTarget.assistant2role_id
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_PickListItem currentTarget ON currentTarget.UniqueId = upTarget.UK_assistant2role_id
        WHERE upTarget.UK_assistant2role_id IS NULL AND upTarget.assistant2role_id IS NOT NULL OR forTarget.PickListItemId <> currentTarget.PickListItemId

        UPDATE upTarget
        SET upTarget.UK_surgeon_of_record_id = forTarget.UniqueID
        FROM PAACS_CaseLog upTarget
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_ShortTermFaculty forTarget ON forTarget.Id = upTarget.surgeon_of_record_id
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_ShortTermFaculty currentTarget ON currentTarget.UniqueId = upTarget.UK_surgeon_of_record_id
        WHERE upTarget.UK_surgeon_of_record_id IS NULL AND upTarget.surgeon_of_record_id IS NOT NULL OR forTarget.id <> currentTarget.id

        UPDATE upTarget
        SET upTarget.UK_anesthesia_id = forTarget.UniqueID
        FROM PAACS_CaseLog upTarget
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_PickListItem forTarget ON forTarget.PickListItemId = upTarget.anesthesia_id
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_PickListItem currentTarget ON currentTarget.UniqueId = upTarget.UK_anesthesia_id
        WHERE upTarget.UK_anesthesia_id IS NULL AND upTarget.anesthesia_id IS NOT NULL OR forTarget.PickListItemId <> currentTarget.PickListItemId

        UPDATE upTarget
        SET upTarget.UK_anesthetist_id = forTarget.UniqueID
        FROM PAACS_CaseLog upTarget
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_ShortTermFaculty forTarget ON forTarget.id = upTarget.anesthetist_id
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_ShortTermFaculty currentTarget ON currentTarget.UniqueId = upTarget.UK_anesthetist_id
        WHERE upTarget.UK_anesthetist_id IS NULL AND upTarget.anesthetist_id IS NOT NULL OR forTarget.id <> currentTarget.id

        UPDATE upTarget
        SET upTarget.UK_anesthetist_Assistant_id = forTarget.UniqueID
        FROM PAACS_CaseLog upTarget
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_ShortTermFaculty forTarget ON forTarget.id = upTarget.anesthetist_Assistant_id
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_ShortTermFaculty currentTarget ON currentTarget.UniqueId = upTarget.UK_anesthetist_assistant_id
        WHERE upTarget.UK_anesthetist_Assistant_id IS NULL AND upTarget.anesthetist_Assistant_id IS NOT NULL OR forTarget.id <> currentTarget.id

        UPDATE upTarget
        SET upTarget.UK_severity_id = forTarget.UniqueID
        FROM PAACS_CaseLog upTarget
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_Severity forTarget ON forTarget.id = upTarget.severity_id
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_Severity currentTarget ON currentTarget.UniqueId = upTarget.UK_severity_id
        WHERE upTarget.UK_severity_id IS NULL AND upTarget.severity_id IS NOT NULL OR forTarget.id <> currentTarget.id

        UPDATE upTarget
        SET upTarget.UK_casetype_id = forTarget.UniqueID
        FROM PAACS_CaseLog upTarget
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_CaseType forTarget ON forTarget.id = upTarget.casetype_id
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_CaseType currentTarget ON currentTarget.UniqueId = upTarget.UK_casetype_id
        WHERE upTarget.UK_casetype_id IS NULL OR forTarget.id <> currentTarget.id

        UPDATE upTarget
        SET upTarget.UK_classification_id = forTarget.UniqueID
        FROM PAACS_CaseLog upTarget
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_Classification forTarget ON forTarget.id = upTarget.classification_id
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_Classification currentTarget ON currentTarget.UniqueId = upTarget.UK_classification_id
        WHERE upTarget.UK_casetype_id IS NULL AND upTarget.casetype_id IS NOT NULL OR forTarget.id <> currentTarget.id

        UPDATE upTarget
        SET upTarget.UK_statusId = forTarget.UniqueID
        FROM PAACS_CaseLog upTarget
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_CaseLogStatus forTarget ON forTarget.id = upTarget.status_id
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_CaseLogStatus currentTarget ON currentTarget.UniqueId = upTarget.UK_statusId
        WHERE upTarget.UK_statusId IS NULL OR forTarget.id <> currentTarget.id

        UPDATE upTarget
        SET upTarget.UK_ASA_id = forTarget.UniqueID
        FROM PAACS_CaseLog upTarget
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_Asa forTarget ON forTarget.ItemId = upTarget.ASA_id
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_Asa currentTarget ON currentTarget.UniqueId = upTarget.UK_ASA_id
        WHERE upTarget.UK_ASA_id IS NULL AND upTarget.ASA_id IS NOT NULL OR forTarget.ItemId <> currentTarget.ItemId

        UPDATE upTarget
        SET upTarget.UK_Resident_id = forTarget.UniqueID
        FROM PAACS_CaseLog upTarget
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_ShortTermFaculty forTarget ON forTarget.Id = upTarget.Resident_id
            LEFT JOIN PAACS_ShortTermFaculty currentTarget ON currentTarget.UniqueId = upTarget.UK_Resident_id
        WHERE upTarget.UK_Resident_id IS NULL AND upTarget.Resident_id IS NOT NULL OR forTarget.id <> currentTarget.id
    END;
```

I ran a Execution Plan on this Trigger and each update relative to batch costs between 2% and 13%.

Ryan

Comment: This trigger is simply broken. It is not referencing the inserted or deleted tables at all. It is updating the entire table over and over. This should be completely rewritten so it updates only the rows needed based on inserted/deleted. And I suspect it could be turned into a single update statement instead of 18.

Comment: Thank you Sean, I was hoping to be able to consolidate it. I am not 100% sure what direction the previous developer was going in, and so we are kind of starting from scratch.

Comment: Seems like starting from scratch would be easier than unraveling this. :)

Comment: Agreed! This happening in 30 other tables too.

Comment: Yikes!!! Glad the person who wrote is no longer there. At least there won't be more of this nightmare stuff being generated. It seems quite strange to have a trigger update the table that was just updated. Seems like something in the design is less than ideal for sure.

Comment: The intent or goal of the program was to sync two servers records and this was somehow going to handle the unique ids (guid)

Comment: You might want to take a look at replication. No need to reinvent the wheel. There is a tried and true solution for this already.

Comment: If your ids are GUID, you also have the potential for another nightmare. IMHO triggers are not much useful beyond logging. The maintenance is a pain and I prefer to keep my business logic/rules at my business layer

Comment: Agreed, this project already has a business logic layer with EF. I will probably move the trigger logic there.